# JetPack - Older Posts Button - Infinite Scroll - how do I change the text?

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I am trying to change the text on the "Older Posts" button on a friend's Wordpress website... I found this (https://gist.github.com/jeherve/6177741) --- I just am not sure where to paste this in the functions.php file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Liz

Answer (score 0):

The gist you've linked can be placed ANYWHERE in your *functions.php* file.

The output from functions hooked onto the `wp_footer` action will appear in the  `get_footer()` location of your theme - generally at the very end of the page.

Read more:

- [Wordpress actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)
- [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer)
- [`get_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)

```php
<?php

function jeherve_custom_infinite_more() { 
if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    infiniteScroll.settings.text = "Custom Text";
    //]]>
    </script>
<?php }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'jeherve_custom_infinite_more', 3 );
```